# Repeated but uniform memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

In my code I have a sequence of calls to malloc (in a loop). Each call allocates a small amount of memory. Since the sequential allocations are of the same size, and their numbers are known in advance, I wonder whether this is suboptimal - the memory manager should be able to take advantage of these information in order to improve heap non-fragmentation and speed.

I cannot simple allocate a contiguous array, because I will need to delete single items.

Is there a function in C (library extension) that allows for such an improvement?

Comment: _I cannot simple allocate a contiguous array, because I will need to delete single items._ What do you mean by that? You mean `free()` specific memory allocated spaces during the execution?

Comment: Show your code, and you might get answers that are more useful for your specific needs.

Comment: _I cannot simple allocate a contiguous array, because I will need to delete single items._ You can allocate your big array and resize it if you want to free some memory, or even you can manage your big array like memory and keep at mind that you've free some memory and can "realocate" it, without free / aloc.

Comment: On modern systems there is not much penalty for keeping allocations arround as long as you don't touch the pages. Why not have a simple counter of the elements that you have deleted, and free the contiguous  array, once you have them all deleted?